# Access Import Data from a folder if its not in the DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have to Loop through a folder and then Import every file that is not in the DB.

With that said there is another program that needs to use the files after mine, I have the whole Import code but I do not know how to set the Import in order to only Import what is new.

ATM it does Import all files from folder XXX and then moves them to a backup folder.

I would like that it copies them to the backup folder and then only imports the new data.

```
ReDim Preserve FileArray(1000)

Do While strFileName <> "" 
FileArray(Y) = strFolder & "\" & strFileName
strFileName = Dir
Y = Y + 1

Loop

nr = Y

Y = Y - 1

If Y = -1 Then
MsgBox ("Keine Daten zum Importieren verfügbar")
DoCmd.Requery
Exit Sub

Else


ReDim Preserve FileArray(Y)

End If
```

Here would have to be a statement to only import certain files but I do not understand how that is established.

My coding skills are very low.

Thanks for every help!

(Yes I have Googled and searched on this stack.)

Comment: " So I have to Loop through a folder and then Import every file that is not in the DB." - what does it means? Do you store information about imported files? Or you should only import all files from specified folder? Or do you check folder time by time and import that have not been imported earlier?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add this info
I loop through a specific folder and then open each file write the fileinfos into the DB with an SQL statement.

I do not know how to import all the new files after the first import because i loop the folder every 60 sec. and i have moved the file to the backupfolder before so i did not have this problem

Comment: Are you just creating a record with file path and name?

Comment: @June7  how do you mean that? I do not understand what exactly you mean

Comment: So point is this: how are you distinguish file that have to be processed from that have to be ignored?

Comment: Exactly what data do you 'write' to record? Are you embedding file into attachment field? Are you opening a text file and saving its contents to a memo field? What data is in record that can be used to indicate what file it originally came from? Simplest may be to save file name. Code can use name of file in folder and see if that file name is already in table.

Comment: @VanNg well i acctualli would just need a way to only import the new filesnto the DB - is that possible?

Comment: @alex how do you, as user, select `new` files? Their name different, you look a list of imported files? How?

Comment: @VanNg theese files are like this: XXX.ETI   and I do Search for *.ETI and the user does not have to search anything in the files.

Comment: Ok. You have: 111.ETI, 222.ETI, 333.ETI. Which of them are `new`? How you find `new` files?

Comment: @VanNg yes this is my question: i have 111.eti,222.eti import them into the db then assume its 2h later 333.eti  i want to import this file then

Comment: @alex, so you have several solutions. 1st variant: move files after processing to another folder (e.g. `ProcessedFiles`), so that program will always process any file that stored in current folder. 2nd variant: create a table, that will contain names of processed files, and compare files in folder with list of processed files

Comment: @VanNg oh okay so i have mooved the files before but this option is no longer possible how do i „sync“ the table during the import?

Comment: Please explain, what does your program do? By logic: 1. I move through each file 2. For each file I 2.1 import it and 2.2 move to other folder... Because I don't understand your `sync` word. What does it mean? Try to explain your task in terms of problem, rather than solution?

Comment: @VanNg  What I mean is how do I Compare the table with the Folder?

Comment: @alex, what is the goal of comparing table with the folder? Do you mean you want to compare list of files in table with list of files in folder? Be more detailed, please, large part of your thoughts is only in your mind, as I see, you need to express them

Comment: @VanNg  okay so I want to import files from folder xy to my DB that does work atm but after that I move the files so I do not run into an error trying to import a file twice. I want to comparte the folder xy with my table tab_xy so I can exclude the files from importing if they are on the list. And i do not know how i compare my array with a table of my DB

Comment: So you have to do following steps: 1. Get list of already imported files from `tab_xy` 2. Scan folder `xy` for list of files. 3. For each file, that in folder `xy` and not in table `tab_xy`: a. import file b. add file name to file list in table `tab_xy`. Correct?

Comment: @VanNg do you have a script part of this? because as I mentioned i am not that good at programming. would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You have some different options, depending on particulars that you are not providing.

1. If the data in the imported files have unique, non-repeating qualities like sequence numbers or time stamps, check whether the records about to be imported already exist in the database.
2. You said that moving the files to a different folder is no longer a good enough solution. How about renaming them? Can `111.ETI` be renamed to `111.imported.ETI` (or in any way be altered so that the filename itself marks it as already imported)?
3. Add a new "imported files" table in your database where you keep track of all the files already imported.
4. Check the creation date/time of each file and keep track of the latest date/time that has been imported. Be careful to use creation date/time and not last modification date/time if the files are accessed by other sources as well.
5. If you have any control of how the source files are being generated/named, make sure the filenames themselves are sequential and keep track of the last imported file.